# check the alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, alphabetical

I am a newbie who is trying hard to have a grip on javascript. please help me to consolidate my fundamentals.

input will be  a string of letters.

following are the requirements.

function should return true if following conditions satisfy:

1. letters are in alphabetical order. (case insensitive)
2. only one letter is passed as input. example :

> ```
> isAlphabet ('abc') === true
>
> isAlphabet ('aBc') === true
>
> isAlphabet ('a') === true
>
> isAlphabet ('mnoprqst') === false 
>
> isAlphabet ('') === false
>
> isAlphabet ('tt') === false
> ```

```
function isAlphabet(letters) {
    
    const string = letters.toLowerCase();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        
        const diff = string.charCodeAt(i + 1) - string.charCodeAt(i);
        
        if (diff === 1) {
            
            continue;
            
        } else if (string === '') {
            
            return false;
            
        } else if (string.length === 1) {
            
            return true;
            
        } else {
            
            return false;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return true;
    
}
```

Comment: You can utilize native .sort() method to sort alphabetically and compare your source string to it. (n log(n)) solution it'd be though.

Comment: 2 suggestions: (1) place all conditions pertaining to string size before your loop; (2) in the loop definition `i+1` should be less than the string size.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a better practice to start your function off with dealing with the edge-cases rather than putting them somewhere in the middle. That way, the function returns as soon as it can - and it's  a lot easier to read than a waterfall of `if..else` statements.

```
function isAlphabet(letters) {
    if ("" == letters) { 
        return false;
    }
    if (1 == letters.length) {
        return true;
    }

    const string = letters.toLowerCase();
    // carry on with your loop here.
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but it can be simplified to just fail on a particular error condition, i.e when a smaller character follows a larger one:

```js
function isAlphabet(letters) {
    const string = letters.toLowerCase();
    let lastChar;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        // Grab a character
        let thisChar = string.charCodeAt(i);
        
        // Check for the failure case, when a lower character follows a higher one
        if (i && (thisChar < lastChar)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Store this character to check the next one
        lastChar = thisChar;
    }
    
    // If it got this far then input is valid
    return true;
}

console.log(isAlphabet("abc"));
console.log(isAlphabet("aBc"));
console.log(isAlphabet("acb"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple way to achieve the same as below

```js
function isAlphabet(inputString)
{
  var sortedString = inputString.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("");
  return sortedString == inputString.toLowerCase();
}

console.log("abc = " + isAlphabet("abc"));
console.log("aBc = " + isAlphabet("aBc"));
console.log("acb = " + isAlphabet("acb"));
console.log("mnoprqst = " + isAlphabet("mnoprqst"));
```

**Note: Mark the answer is resolves your problem.**